# How to write comments under each matrix?

Tags: labels

I would like to write long sentences under each matrix. How can I do that in multi lines?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
A=\left[\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 1&  &    &   &   &   &  &   &   &   &   &\\
 & 1 &  &    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &\\
& & 1 &  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\
&   &   &  1&  &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ 
&   &    &   & 1 &  &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
&   &    &  &  & 1 &  &   &   &   &   &\\
&   &    &    &   & & 1 &  &   &   &   & \\
&   &    &    &   &   &  & 1 &  &  &   &  \\
&   &    &    &   &   &   &  &1 &  &   &  \\ 
&   &    &    &   &   &   &  &  & 1 & & \\
&   &    &    &   &   &   &   &   &  & 1 &  \\
&   &    &    &   &   &   &   &   &   &  & 1 
\end{array}\right],\qquad
B=\left[\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
2&  &    &   &   &   &  &   &   &   &   &\\
 & 2 &  &    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &\\
& & 1 &  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\
&   &   &  1&  &   &   &   &   &   &  \\ 
&   &    &   & 2 &  &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
&   &    &  &  & 1 &  &   &   &   &   &\\
&   &    &    &   & & 1 &  &   &   &   & \\
&   &    &    &   &   &  & 2 &  &  &   &  \\
&   &    &    &   &   &   &  &1 &  &   &  \\ 
&   &    &    &   &   &   &  &  & 1 & & \\
&   &    &    &   &   &   &   &   &  & 2 &  \\
&   &    &    &   &   &   &   &   &   &  & 1 
\end{array}\right].
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is in the matrix? Because they are now empty, brackets are very close to each other ... consequently there is no much space space for a long text ...

Comment: I have edited them. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming, that text below matrices describe them is sensibel to use a sort of `underbrace`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newlength\ubwidth
\newcommand\parunderbrace[2]{\settowidth\ubwidth{$#1$}%
                             \underbrace{#1}_{\parbox{\ubwidth}{%
                                \scriptsize\centering#2}}%\Centering \RaggedRight
                             }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \[\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
      \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
      \setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
A = \parunderbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
 1  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1   
    \end{bmatrix}}{There is some pretty long multi line description for a rather short matrix}
    ,\qquad
B = \parunderbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
 2  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    & 2 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   & 2 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   & 2 &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 2 &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 
    \end{bmatrix}}{There is some pretty long description of matrix}.
\]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.